# Use first xml result in second query of xml

Tags: c#, xml

Here is the first query for xml:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(p.text);
var texts = doc.Descendants("Text")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("section") == SectionName)
    .Select(e => new Text
        {
            AudioList = (string)e.Attribute("audio"),
            Content = (string)e.Value,
            Group_Name = (string)e.Attribute("group")
        })
    .Distinct();
```

and want to use result of query in second one that is

```
var audio = XDocument.Parse(p.audio);
var audios = audio.Descendants("Audio")
    .Where(
        (e => e.Attribute("group") == (texts.Where(dr => dr.Group_Name))) 
        &&
        (e => e.Attribute("File_name")) == (texts.Where(dr => dr.AudioList))
    )
    .Select(e => new Audio
        {
            Path = (string)e.Attribute("Path")
        })
    .Distinct();
```

XML:

```
<Texts>
    <Text group="Outbuilding0">blank</Text>
    <Text group="Study0" audio="abc.wav" section="Walls and skirting">[[Walls and skirting]] </Text>
    <Text group="Study0" audio="c.wav" section="Walls and skirting">[[Walls and skirting]] </Text>
</Texts>
  <Audio group="Outbuilding0">
    <File_name>2013042517364073_Outbuilding0_1.wav</File_name>
    <Path>/Job_Files/74/2_Outbuilding0/Audio/2013042517364073_Outbuilding0_1.wav</Path>
    <Size>32</Size>
    <Audio_length>00:00:04</Audio_length>
  </Audio>
```

But shows me error of `can not convert implicitly from string to bool` in where condition..what is the correct way?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this part: `Where(dr => dr.Group_Name)`?

Comment: Can you show us sample of your xml?

Comment: I want to compare text's groupname with audios' groupname @MártonMolnár

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want `audios` to contain.  Only those where the group & file_name exist in the `Text`s?  If there's any association between a `Text` and an `Audio` you're not going to know what that is afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is coming from the

`Where(dr => dr.Group_Name)`.

You need to provide the where clause with a boolean to evaluate. You want something like

`.Where(dr => dr.Group_Name == e.Group_Name)`

I'm not quite sure what you're after, but;

```
 XDocument document = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

            var texts = from t in document.Descendants("Text")
                        select new
                        {
                            AudioList = t.Attribute("audio") != null ? t.Attribute("audio").Value : string.Empty,
                            Content = t.Value,
                            Group_Name = t.Attribute("group") != null ? t.Attribute("group").Value : string.Empty
                        };

            var audio = from a in document.Descendants("Audio")
                        let groupName = a.Attribute("group") != null ? a.Attribute("group").Value : string.Empty
                        let fileName = a.Element("File_name") != null ? a.Element("File_name").Value : string.Empty
                        let t = texts.Where(t => t.Group_Name == groupName && t.AudioList == fileName)
                        where t.Any()
                        select new
                        {
                            Path = a.Element("Path").Value
                        };
```

What you need to do is verify that the list of texts contains an entry for the audio that you're after. I think that's what your query is trying to do. Obviously, if everything comes out empty you'll get a result (I'm not sure what assumptions you're making about the schema)

Comment: I have to check groupname of audio with text result audios.. I cant get what is ` e.Group_Name)`

Comment: So something like `.Where( e => texts.Any(t => t.GroupName == e.Attribute("group"))) && texts.Any(t => t.AudioList == e.Attribute("File_name"))`? (cant debug your nor mine code right now, but basically, @Hammerstein is right, you have to write where like `.Where(x == y)` but you have only `Where(x)` -- x what...

Comment: @Hammerstein - you can just cast the attribute to string - if it's null, it returns null:  e.g. `(string)t.Attrbute("audio")` will return the same as  `t.Attribute("audio")  != null ? t.Attribute("audio").Value : null`.  Makes for easier reading!